# Algorithm for removing interior elements in a tetrahedral mesh

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I am rendering a tetrahedral mesh in OpenGL. Each tetrahedron is drawn using a triangle for each face (for a total of 4 triangles per tetrahedron). I am looking for a simple way to remove the interior elements of the mesh. For example, if the shape of the mesh was a unit sphere (centered about the origin), I could average the three coordinates of each face in the tetrahedron, and only draw the face that maximizes the distance away from the origin. This would produce a spherical shell.

The meshes that I am working with are more complicated than a sphere :).

Comment: Does the mesh have a watertight exterior? Is the mesh convex?

Comment: @JohnCalsbeek Yes, the mesh will have a watertight exterior. I believe the mesh could be concave. I have one mesh that is rectangular prism with a semi-circle removed from one side. This would be concave, right?

Comment: @Styne666 I'm not sure if I understand point-triangle testing. I have thought about doing something similar to what (I believe) you are describing. 


I just have trouble with defining what `inside` is. The mesh could be anywhere in space. How do I know what interior is? I could find the center of the mesh and go from there, but what if the mesh is convex and the 'center' that I found is outside of the mesh? Then I would be achieving the opposite effect of finding the edges.

Comment: I assume your meshes also have well-defined winding? i.e. you can look at a triangle and figure out which way it is facing?

Comment: @JohnCalsbeek All of the elements are defined using the same pattern: [linear elements](http://web.mit.edu/calculix_v2.0/CalculiX/ccx_2.0/doc/ccx/img122.png)

and [quadratic elements](http://web.mit.edu/calculix_v2.0/CalculiX/ccx_2.0/doc/ccx/img123.png). Does that help?

Comment: If a face only belongs to one tetrahedron, isn't that face part of the shell?  Does each face of the shell only belong to one tetrahedron?

Comment: @Kaiged I believe you are right. I am going try this approach. I thought of this, but I am not drawing tetrahedrons directly, I am drawing triangles. The approach still holds with triangles, but the face can belong to more tetrahedrons. It may be easier to redesign my code to use tetrahedrons and abstract the triangles away.

Comment: @Derek Depending on what information you already have in you data structures, you could just make an algorithm to determine that condition.  You don't necessarily have to restructure / redesign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe, based on your description, that a face is part of the shell when it is only part of one tetrahedron.  You can find the number of tetrahedrons that a face is part of by creating lists of connected points to each point of a face.  Then just find how many points in each list are common among all three lists - this is the number of tetrahedrons a face / triangle is part of.

The high-level pseudo code I can think of is:

```
bool isPartOfShell(Triangle triangle)
{ 
  foreach(Point p in triangle)
    make a list of all connected points in p

  x = the number of points common in all lists

  return x == 1;
}
```